# Selenium- How to find a locator for Web Element?

Tags: selenium, xpath

I am working on finding a solution how to generate a Selenium locator to an element:

```
<a name="page" data-role="button" data-mini="true" data-inline="true" href="https://blablabla/bla/bla/bla/?formTemplatesList_start=120" data-aid="paginator-link-last">Last</a>
```

My ideas:

```
 @FindBy(how = How.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, using = "paginator-link-last")
    public WebElement lastTemplateButton;

 @FindBy(how = How.XPATH, using = "//a[@data-aid='paginator-link-last']")
    public WebElement lastTemplateButton;
```

It does not work... I have no other ideas.

I receive NULL POINTER EXCEPTION when I run:

```
public void selectTemplateToEdit() {
        CustomWaitImpl.waitForElementDisplayed(editEvalTemplateLocators.getLastTemplateButton());
        editEvalTemplateLocators.getLastTemplateButton().click();
    }
```

Comment: `paginator-link-last` is not text so the first one won't work (the text is `Last`). The second one seems ok, you need to explain more about *it does not work*.

Comment: I receive null pointer exception ( please look at updated post)

Comment: You are unable to click the last link that is an issue?

Comment: Try this xpath `//a[@name="page"]` (name attribute should be unique). Could css select do the trick? That would be this `a[name="page"]`.

Comment: Did you initialize your page objects?

Comment: I initialized Page Objects :)

Comment: How? Please provide [mcve].

Comment: My problem now is resolved :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can you try the following:

```
@FindBy(how = How.XPATH, using = "//a[@data-aid = 'paginator-link-last']")
Public WebElement lastTemplateButton;
```

OR

```
@FindBy(how = How.XPATH, using = "//a[@data-aid = 'paginator-link-last' and contains(text(), Last]")
Public WebElement lastTemplateButton;
```

If any of it works, I would recommend just removing the, `how = How.XPATH` and simply just doing the following code below as a reference:

`@FindBy(using = "//a[@data-aid = 'paginator-link-last' and contains(text(), Last]")`

Answer (score 0):

Try with this xpath and also use webDrver wait

```
//a[contains(text(),'Last')]
```